# Increasing the value of elements in a vector by a given sequence/statement

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a sample dataset for an analysis:

```
set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:10, each = 8),
                AGE=rep(sample(20:40, size=10),each=8),
                YEAR=rep(2011:2014, 10, each = 2),
                HAND=rep(c("LEFT","RIGHT"), 40),
                OUTCOME=(rnorm(80)) )

> d[1:8,]
  ID AGE YEAR  HAND    OUTCOME
1  1  26 2011  LEFT  1.7150650
2  1  26 2011 RIGHT  0.4609162
3  1  26 2012  LEFT -1.2650612
4  1  26 2012 RIGHT -0.6868529
5  1  26 2013  LEFT -0.4456620
6  1  26 2013 RIGHT  1.2240818
7  1  26 2014  LEFT  0.3598138
8  1  26 2014 RIGHT  0.4007715
```

`ID` would be subject, `AGE` is the age of the subject, `YEAR` is the year the measurement was taken, `HAND` is left or right hand, `OUTCOME` is  some measure of outcome.

Now I realized that the `AGE` for each subject should ideally increase by one year for each `YEAR` the subject has been measured, i.e.:

```
26,26,27,27,28,28,29,29
```

I came up with this solution:

```
age <- unique(d$AGE)
AGE2=c()
for(i in 1:10){
  a <- rep(age[i]+0:3, each=2)
  AGE2 <- c(AGE2,a)
                 }                       
d$AGE2 <- AGE2
d[1:8,]

> d[1:8,]
  ID AGE YEAR  HAND    OUTCOME AGE2
1  1  26 2011  LEFT  1.7150650   26
2  1  26 2011 RIGHT  0.4609162   26
3  1  26 2012  LEFT -1.2650612   27
4  1  26 2012 RIGHT -0.6868529   27
5  1  26 2013  LEFT -0.4456620   28
6  1  26 2013 RIGHT  1.2240818   28
7  1  26 2014  LEFT  0.3598138   29
8  1  26 2014 RIGHT  0.4007715   29
```

**Question**: I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this? For example would it be possible to add the "corrected" age right away in the `data.frame()` function above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `duplicated`

```
library(dplyr)
res <-  d %>% 
           group_by(ID) %>%
           mutate(AGE2 =  AGE + cumsum(!duplicated(YEAR))-1)
head(res)

#     ID   AGE  YEAR   HAND    OUTCOME  AGE2
#  <int> <int> <int> <fctr>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    26  2011   LEFT  1.7150650    26
#2     1    26  2011  RIGHT  0.4609162    26
#3     1    26  2012   LEFT -1.2650612    27
#4     1    26  2012  RIGHT -0.6868529    27
#5     1    26  2013   LEFT -0.4456620    28
#6     1    26  2013  RIGHT  1.2240818    28
```

Comment: Thanks! But this only seems to work for `res[res$ID==1,]` vs for example `res[res$ID==2,]`.

Comment: I am sorry @akrun! I just checked again and it is indeed all correct. Not sure what was going on. I will also accept your answer because you answered first.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you can simply group by `ID` and `HAND`:

```
d %>% group_by(ID, HAND) %>% mutate(AGE2 = AGE + (0:(length(AGE)-1)))
Source: local data frame [80 x 6]
Groups: ID, HAND [20]

      ID   AGE  YEAR   HAND    OUTCOME  AGE2
   <int> <int> <int> <fctr>      <dbl> <int>
1      1    26  2011   LEFT  1.7150650    26
2      1    26  2011  RIGHT  0.4609162    26
3      1    26  2012   LEFT -1.2650612    27
4      1    26  2012  RIGHT -0.6868529    27
5      1    26  2013   LEFT -0.4456620    28
6      1    26  2013  RIGHT  1.2240818    28
7      1    26  2014   LEFT  0.3598138    29
8      1    26  2014  RIGHT  0.4007715    29
9      2    35  2011   LEFT  0.1106827    35
10     2    35  2011  RIGHT -0.5558411    35
# ... with 70 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, you could use `rep` and a little algebra.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[, AGE2 := AGE + rep(0L:((.N-1)/2L), each=2), by=ID][]
    ID AGE YEAR  HAND      OUTCOME AGE2
 1:  1  26 2011  LEFT  1.715064987   26
 2:  1  26 2011 RIGHT  0.460916206   26
 3:  1  26 2012  LEFT -1.265061235   27
 4:  1  26 2012 RIGHT -0.686852852   27
 5:  1  26 2013  LEFT -0.445661970   28
 6:  1  26 2013 RIGHT  1.224081797   28
 7:  1  26 2014  LEFT  0.359813827   29
 8:  1  26 2014 RIGHT  0.400771451   29
 9:  2  35 2011  LEFT  0.110682716   35
10:  2  35 2011 RIGHT -0.555841135   35
11:  2  35 2012  LEFT  1.786913137   36
12:  2  35 2012 RIGHT  0.497850478   36
...
```

Here, AGE2 is constructed by adding AGE to `rep(0L:((.N-1)/2L), each=2)` which counts 0 through the number of observations, minus 1, divided by 2. The by statement repeats this for each ID.